# Setting up FTP server on an existing Azure virtual machine - need detailed explanation

Tags: wordpress, azure, ftp

So mildly tech person - need help setting up FTP server on an existing Azure VM that was setup for WordPress.  I was given this link, but don't know how to get to the Server Manager and submenus from the Azure Dashboard - I'm working to get up to speed quickly, but I've been a project manager and not had to get into the guts of this until now ... so be gentle.

https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_ftps_server#installing_ftp_server

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/connect-logon) link to read how to rdp into vm, from there use your article

Comment: It isn't giving me the RDP option - probably the server setup we selected. Instead, it's giving me some command line to connect to the Linux virtual machine via SSH. Can I get it to generate the rdp file through the Cloud Shell?

Comment: no, you need to create a windows server. you've created a linux vm

Comment: The list in your question is for setting up FTP(S) server on Windows  server. If you have created (and mainly if you need) a *nix server, you have to use a different guide.

Comment: Ok, already learning something - didn't even think about the Linux vs Windows setup - should have, but didn't. Ok, so what's next.  Any guides for setting up the FTP on the Linux VM? (Now that I know the question to ask)  :)

Comment: Are you sure you need FTP? What for? Linux servers come with SSH/SFTP. You better use that. Unless you have some specific need for FTP.

Comment: @BRadighieri You could refer to this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32917.how-to-use-azure-linux-vm-as-an-ftp-server.aspx). One thing you need pay attention to if you use ARM mode, you need open port on Azure NSG, not endpoint.